# Is it possible to revert from .NET Core to .NET Framework? (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know this seems silly, but I need some things from the .NET Framework that aren't in .NET Core 6. I am using a C# Windows Form. Is there any way to revert my project back to the .NET Framework?

Comment: Look at the csproj file, its just the `TargetFramework` property

Comment: The new SDK style csproj format can also be used with .NET Framework. It is not tied to .NET Core. You can change the Framework version in the project properties but you will probably have to change some Dependencies (References) manually.

Comment: Change <TargetFramework> in the project file to : `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>`. You need to unload and reload the project after doing that, otherwise it barfs. Then you'll likely have to deal with some incorrect assembly references, but sometimes all is hunky dory.